# fabric crashlytics and firebase push notification in single app(multiple google-service.json)

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, twitter-fabric

I have implemented fabric crashlytics in my app now i try to add firebase push notification.

Now the issue is that I have two google-service.json in a project and at a time only single google-service is working. How to rectify that issue?

[image]

Comment: why not just use firebase crash analytics instead of fabric crashlytics?

Comment: Why you are using two json?

Comment: Why do you think that fabric needs `google-services.json` file?

Comment: fabric is also google tool for crash report it also give u google-service.json

Comment: is it possible to use two different google product in a same app

Comment: Hi! Todd from Fabric. We don't depend on a google-services.json file. Can you provide a screenshot of the other file?